# Can not access a server through Shadowsocks proxy, installed on it.

Tags: proxy, docker, routing

I have a VPS, where, in docker containers, there are a Shadowsocks server on port 8350 and a web-server on default 443 port. I installed them with docker-compose. If I access web-server directly from remote machine, like "https://domain.org/", it works. If I try to access through the Shadowsocks proxy, it does not find web-server.

I guess it is a simple routing problem, but I do not understand it. I did no configuration of networks in docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I avoided the problem by switching proxy container to --network-host, but it is not a proper solution.